# Where does the number 2 exp 32 come from?

Tags: redis

A REDIS instance can store 2exp32 keys. A REIS set can store 2exp32 entries. Where does this number come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2<sup>32</sup> − 1 is the largest number representable by an unsigned 32-bit integer.  For many years, 32 bits was the most common size of a CPU integer register, so that upper limit is baked into programs all over the place.  Nowadays CPUs with 64-bit-wide integer registers are increasingly common, but programmers still often reach for the 32-bit integer first.

Answer (score 2):

2^32 = 4,294,967,296, which is the value you can fit in a 32-bit data type. Sets of 250 million keys have been tested.

More information on [their page](http://redis.io/topics/faq)

Comment: Technically the upper limit is 4,294,967,295, because the lower limit is zero.

Answer (score 2):

2^32 is the number of possible values that can be represented by an 4 byte integer.

Answer (score 1):

2^32 is a 32-bit number. 32-bit is a common size for many database systems.